# SharePoint 2010 list will not letyou add an alert on the newly created page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created some pages on a site and added some standard document lists with the summary toolbar. When I go onto the page it gives me a box on the top left of the list but does not let me set an alert for anything added to this list. I can add an alert to individual documents added to the list container .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to set alert for any action happening to the document list. The link below might help you get the same results, whether on -

- whole list or library
- individual item
- search

http://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the menu you are in is the page menu - this is not the correct place to set alerts for when something in the document libraries change.  If you were to set an alert on the page, you would be alerted when someone changes the page - e.g. if someone edits the page by adding some additional content, like a new web part.

So, although your custom page is displaying document libraries (or lists), the alerts need to be set on the individual document library or list.  This way, when someone e.g. edits a document

The link posted by Satyajit Paul is a good one, the sharepoint maven is a very good blogger.